# Wordpress upload images not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a wordpress site and I upload images to media library but the images do not display. In wp-content/upload folder there are other folders like 2015/ and then in that folder there are folders with names 02 and 03 and o1.

Why none of my images are showing in the medialibrary. Image gets uploaded on this path like for instance this image was uploaded

http://sketchfam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/sketchfam-background-1.png

but the image never displays ... what could be the quick solution I have also updated my wordpress to latest version but still the same problem.

Thanks people

Comment: That image is massive. Maybe your server is timing out before it can generate the different sizes? It's hard to say without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick solution you can download the WordPress plugin photo-gallery https://wordpress.org/plugins/photo-gallery/.

Once it's installed and activated you hover your mouse over Photo Gallery in your WordPress Dashboard and click Add Galleries/images.

Add a new picture or many pictures in a new gallery and save.

When it's done simply hover your mouse over Photo Gallery and click on Generate Shortcode, select the Gallery you created then click on Generate.

Last step, copy-paste the shortcode that the plugin generate and paste it in any post that you want then save your post.

Voilà :)